# Show bootstrap modal as "thank you" after form is submitted

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a contact form i'm working on and i'd like a modal to be displayed when the form is submitted successfully. The problem i'm having is actually getting the form to show and i think my problem is in my javascript (i'm pretty new to it).
Anyway, here's what i'm using:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#agents input:submit').click(function() {
  $('#agents form').attr('action', 'http://' + document.domain + '/agents/php/feedback_custom.php');
  $('#agents form').submit();
 });
 $('form #response').hide();
 $('#submit').click(function(e) {
  // prevent forms default action until
  // error check has been performed
  e.preventDefault();
  // grab form field values
  .....

  if (valid != '') {
                     ....do stuff.....
  }
  // let the user know something is happening behind the scenes
  // serialize the form data and send to our ajax function
  else {
   $('form #response').removeClass().addClass('processing').html('Processing...').fadeIn('fast');          
   var formData = $('form').serialize(); 
   submitForm(formData);   
  }
 });
});
function submitForm(formData) {
 $.ajax({  
  type:   'POST',
  url:   '../agents/php/feedback_custom.php',
  data:   formData,
  dataType: 'json',
  cache:  false,
  timeout: 7000,
  success: 
  function(data) {
   $("#thankyouModal").modal('show');
  },
  error: 
  function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   $('form #response').removeClass().addClass('error')
      .html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' +
       '<p>There was an <strong>ERROR SENDING THE FORM</strong><br>Please make sure you have filled out the required fields and resend the form.</p>' +
           '</div>').fadeIn('fast');
  }
 });
};
```

```html
<head></head>
<body>
           <div class="modal fade" id="thankYouModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg ">
                <div class="modal-content alert alert-success">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title h2"><strong>Your Claim Information Has Been Submitted</strong></h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>modal text</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                  </div>
                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
              </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div><!-- /.modal -->
           <form role="ajaxExample" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="agents">
                  <div id="response"></div>
             <div class="row">
                 <h2 class="h3 headline"><span>Required Fields (<span class="required">*</span>):</span></h2>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 info-board info-board-red">
                     <h4>Customer Information</h4>
                     <!-- customer info here -->
                   </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 info-board info-board-red">
                     <h4>Insurance Information</h4>
                        <!-- insurance info here -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 info-board info-board-red">
                     <h4>Vehicle Information</h4>
                     <!-- vehicle info here -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-sm-12 info-board info-board-blue">
                     <div class="form-group">
                         <label for="spamQuestion">
                             <span class="required">*</span> Anti-spam... Please Solve The Math Problem <span class="required">*</span>:<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <?php
                                $a = rand(1, 10);
                                $b = rand(1, 10);
                                echo $a." + ".$b." = ?";
                        ?>
                         </label>
                            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $a;?>" name="value1" />
                            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $b;?>" name="value2" />                            
                            <input type="text" name="answer" value="what's the result?" onclick="this.value=''" tabindex="26" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <input type="hidden" name="honeypot" id="honeypot" value="http://">
                        <input type="hidden" name="humancheck" id="humanCheck" class="clear" value="">
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="27" class="btn btn-success">Submit Claim</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="reset" name="reset1" value="Reset Form" tabindex="28" class="btn btn-red" />
              <div id="response"></div>
             </div>
                </div>
       </form>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ajax_submit_custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My php:

```
<?php 
sleep(.5);
//Sanitize incoming data and store in variable

//customer info
$policyName = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['policyName'])));           
$homePhone = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['homePhone'])));
$homePhoneLink = preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $homePhone);
$workPhone = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['workPhone'])));
$workPhoneLink = preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $workPhone);
$filerName = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['filerName'])));
$agentOrNot = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['agentOrNot'])));
$replyEmail = '';
if ($_POST['replyEmail'] != '') {
$replyEmail .= $_POST['replyEmail'];
} else {
$replyEmail .= 'noReply@centuryglasssc.com';
}

//insurance info
$policy = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['policy'])));
$insCompany = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['insCompany'])));
$agentName = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['agentName'])));
$vin = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['vin'])));
$compCoverage = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['compCoverage'])));
$dateOfLoss = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['dateOfLoss'])));

//vehicle info
$year = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['year'])));
$make = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['make'])));
$model = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['model'])));
$bodyStyle = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['bodyStyle'])));
$doors = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['doors'])));
$damagedGlass = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['damagedGlass'])));

//spam filters
$humancheck = $_POST['humancheck'];
$honeypot = $_POST['honeypot'];
$answer = $_POST['answer'];
$c = $_POST['value1'] + $_POST['value2'];

if ($honeypot == 'http://' && empty($humancheck)) { 

//Validate data and return success or error message
$error_message = '';    
$reg_exp = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z.]{2,4}$/";


if (empty($policyName)) {
        $error_message .= "<p>POLICYHOLDER NAME IS REQUIRED.</p>";             
}

if (empty($homePhone)) {
        $error_message .= "<p>HOME PHONE IS REQUIRED.</p>";            
}
if (empty($workPhone)) {
        $error_message .= "<p>WORK IS REQUIRED.</p>";              
}



if ($answer != $c) {
            $error_message .=   "<p>PLEASE RE-ENTER YOUR SIMPLE MATH ANSWER AND TRY AGAIN.</p>";
}


if (!empty($error_message)) {
        $return['error'] = true;
        $return['msg'] = '<div class="alert alert-danger">'."<h4>OOPS! THE FORM WAS NOT SUBMITTED.</h4>".$error_message;                    
        echo json_encode($return);
        exit();
} 

else {
//mail variables
#$to =              'info@centuryglasssc.com';
$to =           'mainstwebguy@gmail.com';
$from = $_POST['replyEmail'];
$headers =  'From: '.$from."\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$subject =  "Agent Claim From Website\n";


$body =         '<h4>Customer Information</h4>';
$body .=        '<p>Policyholder:   '.$policyName."<br />";
$body .=        'Home Phone: '.'<a href="tel:+1'.$homePhoneLink.'">'.$homePhone."</a><br />";
$body .=        'Work Phone: '.'<a href="tel:+1'.$workPhoneLink.'">'.$workPhone."</a><br />";
if (isset($_POST['filerName']))     {   $body   .=  $filerName;     }
if (isset($_POST['agentOrNot']))    {   $body   .=  $agentOrNot;    }
if(isset($_POST['replyEmail']))     {   $body   .=  $replyEmail;    }
$body .=        '</p>';



$body .=        '<h4>Insurance Information</h4>';
$body .=        '<p>Policy #: '.$policy.'<br />';
$body .=        'Ins. Company:  '.$insCompany.'<br />';
$body .=        'Agent\'s Name: '.$agency.'<br />';
$body .=        'VIN: '.$vin.'<br />';
$body .=        'Comp Coverage: '.$compCoverage.'<br />';
$body .=        'Date of Loss:  '.$dateOfLoss.'</p>';





$body .=        '<h4>Vehicle Information</h4>';
$body .=        '<p>Year:   '.$year.'<br />';
$body .=        'Make:  '.$make.'<br />';
$body .=        'Model: '.$model.'<br />';
$body .=        'Body Style:    '.$bodyStyle.'<br />';
$body .=        'Number of Doors:   '.$doors.'<br />';
$body .=        'Damaged Glass: '.$damagedGlass.'</p>';



//send email and return a message to user
if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {  
    $return['error'] = false;
    $return['msg'] = 
        '<div class="alert alert-success">'.
            "<h4>Thank you for using our form </h4>".
            "<p>We'll reply to you as soon as we can.</p>";

            echo json_encode($return);
}
else {

    $return['error'] = true;
    $return['msg'] = "<h4>Oops! There was a problem sending the email. Please try again.</h4>"; 
    echo json_encode($return);
}

}

} 
else {

$return['error'] = true;
$return['msg'] = "<h4>Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please try again.</h4>";  
echo json_encode($return);
}

?>
```

One thing to note is that I am receiving the email from the form, it's just that the modal isn't firing.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe jQuery selectors are case sensitive.

When you call:

```
$("#thankyouModal").modal('show');
```

I believe it should be:

```
$("#thankYouModal").modal('show');
```

Comment: stupid typos! thank you for lending a sharper pair of eyes than i have :)

Comment: Hey Jason, I got that issue sorted, but now the form isn't requiring the required fields, and it's firing the modal even if the form doesn't send (because required fields aren't filled in. I know it's another issue in my javascript (at least i think), but can't seem to find it :( I can PM you a link if you want to see the live version, let me know.